# How to remove the path with an nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, path, proxypass

I have a running web-application at `http://example.com/`, and want to "mount" another application, on a separate server on `http://example.com/en`. Upstream servers and `proxy_pass` seem to work, but for one issue:

```
upstream luscious {
 server lixxxx.members.linode.com:9001;
}

server {
  root /var/www/example.com/current/public/;
  server_name example.com;

  location /en {
    proxy_pass http://luscious;
  }
}
```

When opening `example.com/en`, my upstream application returns `404 not found /en`. This makes sense, as the upstream does not have the path `/en`.

Is `proxy_path` the right solution? Should I rewrite "upstream" so it listens to `/en` instead, as it root path? Or is there a directive that allows me to rewrite the path passed along to upstream?

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130841/removing-start-of-path-from-nginx-proxy-pass

Answer (score 320, accepted):

This is likely the most efficient way to do what you want, without the use of any regular expressions:

```
location = /en {
    return 302 /en/;
}
location /en/ {
    proxy_pass http://luscious/;  # note the trailing slash here, it matters!
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, the last part would still pass "/en" as path along to the proxy, not?

Comment: @berkes, no, it won't -- the trailing slash in `proxy_pass` is what makes a difference.  Also, this answer is more correct than the one you came up with, because it also ensures that [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect) stays at `default`, so, you could still use `302` et al within your backend, and have it work correctly everywhere.

Comment: Doesn't looks like it works. Here's what luscious would get: "GET /en/ HTTP/1.0" 404 I.e. it's proxied along with a path

Comment: @Vanuan, no idea what you mean, or where `/docs/` come from!  Everything in the answer should still work 100%.

Comment: Ah, I was missing the trailing slash :(

Comment: AAARGH! TRAILING SLASH !

Comment: 3 hours of searching, and yeah... It was the trailing slash. Thanks mate!

Comment: Soo... what does the trailing slash do?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat it just specifies that there's a path specified for the mapping; otherwise, no mapping is assumed, and paths are passed as-is.

Comment: That goddamned trailing slash wasted my time

Comment: Works for me well, but beware, doesn't work in combination with directive try_files!!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with variable upstream either. Hmm. `location "/in/" { set $upstream  'service:port'; proxy_pass http://$upstream/; }`  Still calls service with `GET /in/` Hmm. Purpose of variable upstream it to allow nginx to be up before service is up.  Just gets bad gateway until service IS up, but doesn't prevent nginx itself.

Comment: @JesseChisholm variables are a special case, see http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass; tl;dr: use something like `proxy_pass http://$upstream$uri;`

Comment: The documentation says that URI `http://in/some/path` should in my example be proxied as `http://$upstream/some/path` (because I have a trailing slash after $upstream) with the matched `/in` removed.  I'm seeing the lead part remain.  I don't want the entire `$uri` I want the portion AFTER the match in location.

Comment: Finally found what works for me: `location ~* ^/in/(.*)$ { set $upstream server:port; proxy_pass http://$upstream/$1; }` so the regex matches the part I want to remove, and the `$1` puts it back where I want it.  And I still get to use my variable upstream. :)

Comment: @JesseChisholm if you're using variables in `proxy_pass`, you don't have to switch to regex in `location`, you can merely use `$uri` in place of the `$1` with a corresponding non-regex location.

Comment: @cnst I wouldn't have bothered with the regex form if the `$uri` form worked for me. But using `location = /in/ { set $upstream ...; proxy_pass http://$upstream/$uri; }` the request `https://target/in/health` gets translated as `http://upstream/in/health` which is not what I want, `http://upstream/health`.

Comment: @JesseChisholm you're right; I think I forgot to mention also using `rewrite`; I'd probably use a static location, rewrite, and then `$uri` in proxy_pass, but I guess it might be all the same and/or classified as a premature optimisation.

Comment: In production, I use the actual hostname to distinguish which internal service to proxy to. But this is in development where I don't have DNS mapping many hosts to one IP for me, so I needed a backdoor to test with. So, yes, static locations per actual hostname is _much_ better.

Comment: I have configured as per above verified answer but it did not work for me. and my configuration are as below. looking for help.

Comment: server {
        server_name  abc.com.np www.abc.com.np;
        root  /home/nsec/nsec-fe;
        index  index index.html index.htm index.html;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/abc.com.np/abc.com.np.access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/abc.com.np/abc.com.np.errors.log;
        location / {
        root  /home/nsec/nsec-fe;
        index  index index.html index.htm index.html;
        }
           location /images/ {
              root      /home/backend/cdn;
           }
        location /api/ {
           proxy_pass http://api;
        }

}

Comment: Could you add a note for *both* trailing slashes? The fact you only referenced one meant I missed the second...

Comment: It is worth mentioning that if you have an HTML document that has references to other assets (CSS, image, etc.) that start with '/', then the request to the HTML document will be successful while requests for the other assets will fail.

Answer (score 22):

I'd like to address a newer regex-based answer that's been rising in popularity.

```
location ~ ^/en(/?)(.*)$ {  # OOPS!
  proxy_pass http://luscious/$2$is_args$args;  # OOPS!
}
```

The solution may seem more cute at first glance, but it's wrong for multiple reasons.

- The above regex would match a request uri of `/enjoy`, redirecting it to `/joy` upstream.  Is this really intended?
- A request for `/en` will not result in any redirects, directly serving a `/` from the upstream (almost as if a request for `/en/` was made instead, but not quite).  If you use relative URIs within your root page upstream (otherwise, why wouldn't you have the `/en/` prefix right there within the upstream URIs?), e.g. `src="style.css"` (which might reference a language-specific `url("menu.png")`, for example), then the browser will request that as `/style.css` instead of `/en/style.css`.  (Or even if you use absolute URIs everywhere, what if someone references an obscure semi-optional resource relatively?)  Oops, suddenly the site may not work, but only sometimes or in edge cases.
- As per my [earlier advice at another question already mentioned by the OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20722311/1122270), using regular expressions prevents the [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect) directive from having the default value of `default`, turning it down to `off` instead.  This means that if the upstream replies with `Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080/en/dir/` when a request for `/en/dir` is made, then that's what the client will see, which obviously won't work correctly.  (Which would have been especially ironic for a `/en` request which prompts regex use in the first place, yet this specific implementation instead suffers from another problem as already mentioned above.)  Plus, if you're already using the [`upstream`](http://nginx.org/r/upstream) directive, then it might get extra ugly if you just try to go with a custom one, especially if you may have more than one upstream server — how do you have a separate `proxy_redirect` for each one of those?  You could use regular expressions within `proxy_redirect`, too, maybe even to match any host, but then what if you decide to give a cross-domain redirect in the future?

To try to address some of the above points with a single regex-based location, we could do the following (note that in `proxy_pass` we also had to drop the reference to a server from an `upstream`-based directive, to make `proxy_redirect` more straightforward):

```
location ~ ^/en/?((?<=/).*)?$ {
  location = /en { return 302 /en/; }
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1$is_args$args;
  proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/ /en/;
}
```

So, if you ask me, the [original solution with the two sibling top-level locations](https://serverfault.com/a/562850/110020) would still be a better idea than digging yourself into a rabbit hole by going the regex route instead.

Comment: This causes an exception:
`nginx: [emerg] location "/en" is outside location "^/en/?((?<=/).*`

Comment: @Athlan, that's because you shouldn't really be using that in the first place!  If you still want to, you can put that location outside of the regexp.

Comment: puting localation = /en outside works really fine! thanks

Comment: Also wrong when you have spaces in your URLs, `$2` will not re-encode a space as `+` or `%20` and the upstream will get a real space in the URL which is invalid. I filed this as a bug but the NGINX maintainer disagrees.

Answer (score 10):

So, I found the [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12367917/73673):

```
upstream luscious {
 server lixxxx.members.linode.com:9001;
}

server {
  root /var/www/example.com/current/public/;
  server_name example.com;

  location ~ ^/en(/?)(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://luscious/$2;
  }
}
```

Basically: passing a regex into location and passing the backref along to the proxy_pass url.

Comment: I think "proxy_pass http://luscious/$;" should be "proxy_pass http://luscious/$2"

Comment: @Zafer is right, the above answer was giving me an error

Comment: I've changed the answer, but don't have a server at hand where I can try this, ATM, so it is not verified.

Comment: This would seem to proxy `/english` to `http://luscious/glish` which doesn't seem desirable.

Answer (score 6):

Accounting to [Nginx documents](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

To pass a request to an HTTP proxied server, the proxy_pass directive is specified inside a location. For example:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
}
```

This example configuration results in passing all requests processed in this location to the proxied server at the specified address. This address can be specified as a domain name or an IP address. The address may also include a port:

```
location ~ \.php {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

Note that in the first example above, the address of the proxied server is followed by a URI, /link/. If the URI is specified along with the address, it replaces the part of the request URI that matches the location parameter. For example, here the request with the /some/path/page.html URI will be proxied to http://www.example.com/link/page.html. If the address is specified without a URI, or it is not possible to determine the part of URI to be replaced, the full request URI is passed (possibly, modified).

Comment: Why isn't this the correct answer? It provides the correct approach using the built-in tools of nginx instead of clumsy regex patterns

Answer (score 0):

I had a play with the accepted solution above but found it was causing dodgy redirects for all the CSS and JS assets.
In the end, I found inspiration from the way that the LinuxServer SWAG Nginx configurations are done. You can find them [here](https://github.com/linuxserver/reverse-proxy-confs). Take a look at `pihole.subfolder.conf.sample`.

As such, my solution looks like this:

```
location /en {
    return 302 $scheme://$host/en/;
}

location ^~ /en/ {
    set $upstream_app lixxxx.members.linode.com;
    set $upstream_port 9001;
    set $upstream_proto http;
    proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

    rewrite /en(.*) $1 break;
}
```