# Nginx reverse proxy too many redirections

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect

I want to configure nginx to act as a reverse proxy that will redirect to two different Kibana hosts depending on the passed URI. `/` redirect to the standard and `/october/` to the october dedicated Kibana. The first part of the configuration (`/`) works well but I got a `Too many redirections` error when a try to access `/october`. I tried to comment out the second part (`location /october/`) and replace `localhost` by `10.10.0.3` in the first one and I'm redirected to the october platform. So the problem is on this nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             my.domain.io;
    return                  301 https://$server_name;
}

server {
    listen                  443 ;
    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.io/cert.pem;  
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.io/privkey.pem;  
    server_name             my.domain.io; 
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/kibana.access.log;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/kibana.error.log;

    location / {
            auth_basic              "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.htpasswd;


            location / {
                    proxy_pass              http://localhost:5601;
                    proxy_http_version      1.1;
                    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
            }

            location /october/ {
                    proxy_pass              http://10.10.0.3:5601;
                    proxy_http_version      1.1;
                    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the `ssl` directive in your `listen` directive. HTTPS doesn't work with this configuration.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Docs say: `It is recommended to use the ssl parameter of the listen directive instead of this directive.` Hence his config must still work with `ssl on;`

Comment: @TeroKilkanen The SSL configuration works well with Let's encrypt as the CA. The problem is about the second location `/october/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the previous responses, I found the solution but don't exactly know "how" and "why" it works...

Here is my new configuration :

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             my.domain.io;
    return                  301 https://$server_name;
}

server {
    listen                  443 ;
    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.io/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.io/privkey.pem;
    server_name             my.domain.io;
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/kibana.access.log;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/kibana.error.log;

    auth_basic              "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.htpasswd;

    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:5601;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
    }

    location = /october {
            return 302 /october/;
    }

    location /october/ {
            proxy_pass              http://10.10.0.3:5601/;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

There is no need for `proxy_redirect` directive.
The trick was to add a `/` at the end of the `/october` location and redirect `/october` to `/october/`whit 302 code.
Don't forget that you have to set `server.basePath` to `"/october"`in your kibana.yml file.

This post helped me : [How to remove the path with an nginx proxy_pass](https://serverfault.com/questions/562756/how-to-remove-the-path-with-an-nginx-proxy-pass)

Hope this will help...

Comment: If `return 302 /october/` solved your problem, then my (again) edited answer should also work for you. Can you please confirm?

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana4.conf:35
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: Did you remove trailing slash? `http://10.10.0.3:5601;`

Comment: I did not but I've done it and I got a `{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}` coming from Kibana I suppose.

Comment: Thanks. That means it's working, only kibana cannot understand `/october`

Answer (score 2):

I think you have had your `locations` nested incorrectly, please try the following:

```
server {
    listen                  443 ;
    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.io/cert.pem;  
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.io/privkey.pem;  
    server_name             my.domain.io; 
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/kibana.access.log;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/kibana.error.log;

    auth_basic              "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.htpasswd;

    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:5601;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
    }

    location ~ ^/october.*$ {
            proxy_pass              http://10.10.0.3:5601;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried you configuration but stills not work `Too many redirections` in Safari. But thank you for informing me that this `double-nested location loop` was not necessary (I get the configuration file from an other nginx server and I'm totaly new to nginx).

Comment: Are you saying you get that redirection loop only on `Safari`? If so please make sure to clear browser cache before you re-try.

Comment: No, I got this error in every browser (at least Chrome and Safari). I cleared the cache, same problem...

Comment: Please try edited config.

Comment: The `Too many redirections` errors disappeared but now, I reach the first (localhost) Kibana in any case... So strange...

Comment: How do you access your october kibana? Using `/october` or `/october/`?

Comment: I tried both of them and it's the same result. It returns the original "localhost" Kibana

Comment: @Kuaaaly As suggested in the other answer try to play a little with [proxy_redirect](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive. I think you may actually want to use `off` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

With the configuration given, requests to `/october/some/path` will be passed as-is to your second Kibana host, which is probably not configured to expect requests prefixed with `/october`.

I don't know Kibana but a quick search brought me to the [configuration documentation for 5.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html) which has a `server.basePath` configuration value. Try setting this to "/october".

In addition, as the docs say this value only affects the URLs generated by Kibana you will need to add a `proxy_redirect` directive to the nginx configuration and modify the `proxy_pass` nginx directive, appending a `/` to the backend URL:

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             my.domain.io;
    return                  301 https://$server_name;
}

server {
    listen                  443 ;
    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.io/cert.pem;  
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.io/privkey.pem;  
    server_name             my.domain.io; 
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/kibana.access.log;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/kibana.error.log;

    location / {
            auth_basic              "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.htpasswd;


            location / {
                    proxy_pass              http://localhost:5601;
                    proxy_http_version      1.1;
                    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
            }

            location /october/ {
                    proxy_pass              http://10.10.0.3:5601/;
                    proxy_redirect          /   /october/;
                    proxy_http_version      1.1;
                    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
            }
    }
}
```

`proxy_redirect` rewrites URLs returned in "Location" and "Refresh" headers, and the additional slash causes the proxy module to strip off the path matched by the nginx "location" directive. These effectively compliment each other.

Comment: Thank you so much guys (both of you). I've successfully set up a viable solution by mixing your different propositions. I'll detailed it in an other post bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual reason was in a single character, note the **trailing slash /**:

`proxy_pass              http://10.10.0.3:5601;`
                    `proxy_pass              http://10.10.0.3:5601/;`

Just had the same problem with Nginx URI proxying Kibana too.

TLDR: trailing slashes in Nginx proxy configuration are VERY important (both in `location` and `proxy_pass`). Rule of thumb: have them, unless you know, what you do.

- Official documentation (slightly hard to digest), http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass
- This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759345/nginx-trailing-slash-in-proxy-pass-url tries to explain it differently.

P.S. My Nginx and Kibana 8.8.0.0 configuration:

```
  auth_basic           "Administrator's area";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

  location /kibana/ {
    proxy_pass http://kibana:5601/kibana/`enter code here`;
    proxy_set_header Authorization  "";
  }
```

```yaml
  kibana:
    << : *service_defaults
    image: ${KIBANA_IMAGE}
    profiles: ['ui']
    ports: ["5601:5601"]
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD}
      # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html
      - SERVER_BASEPATH=/kibana
      - SERVER_REWRITEBASEPATH=true
    healthcheck:
      << : *healthcheck_defaults
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "curl -L -u elastic:$ELASTIC_PASSWORD http://localhost:5601/kibana/api/status | grep 'All services are available'", ]
    depends_on: { elasticsearch: { condition: service_healthy }}
```