# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when setting up NGINX proxy in front of NGINX proxy and moodle in k8s

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, moodle

I have a pod running moodle and it has NGINX in front of it. The configuration of it is here:
https://github.com/google/moodle-on-gcp/blob/main/4-moodle-image-builder/base/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

In my ingress, requests come in under `/moodle`, however as you can see the backend configuration expects requests to come in at `/`. So I deployed an NGINX proxy in front of it with the following configuration:

```
location /moodle/ {
  proxy_pass http://moodle.moodle.svc.cluster.local:80/;
}
```

essentially I want to strip `/moodle` from the request and forward it to the backend. With this configuration however I see `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

I tried several different configurations but I cannot get this to work

Comment: Have you checked which redirects is that? Try running `curl -IL <link>` in CLI where you'll see locations to which it's redirecting you.

Comment: In general when you connect to the default port in an URL the port number must be omitted. 80 is the default port for clear text HTTP and  `http://<host>:80/` should be  `http://<host>/`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/821997/nginx-reverse-proxy-too-many-redirections) on redirecting the proxy_pass to localhost.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
}
```

Since the [moodle ingress](https://github.com/google/moodle-on-gcp/blob/main/8-ingress/nginx-ingress-external-this-is-optional.yaml) uses [pathType: ImplementationSpecific](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#resource-backend) you may modify this to a proper service wherein your backend is located.

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
  - host: moodle.<YOUR-LB-EXTERNAL-IP>.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: moodle
              port:
                number: 80
```