# How to remove the path with an nginx proxy_pass in http and https?

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have read the similar issue below but got a problem that will explain later in the question:

- [How to remove the path with an nginx proxy_pass](https://serverfault.com/questions/562756/how-to-remove-the-path-with-an-nginx-proxy-pass)

I have a config like below that `proxy_pass` to an `upstream`:

```
location /api2/ {
    client_max_body_size 10m;

    if ($scheme = 'https') {
        proxy_pass https://api.example.com;
    }

    if ($scheme = 'http') {
        proxy_pass http://api.example.com;
    }

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
}
```

Here the `api2` section is sent to the upstream. In the question I've linked above uses `/` at the end of `proxy_pass` to omit the `api2` part. When I add the `/` at the end of `proxy_pass` I get the below error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite:160
```

When I searched for the above error, the community says that you need to remove `/` in proxy_pass to solve the error.

So the question is why I'm getting `api2` in the upstream? How should I remove `api2` when proxying?

When I change the config to:

```
location /api2/ {
    client_max_body_size 10m;

    proxy_pass http://api.example.com/;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
}
```

It works, but the `https` requests have problem sending request.

In the upstream section I get the below error:

```
GET //api2/my_endpoint HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Comment: The problem is that you put `proxy_pass` inside `if`, which isn't allowed when it has a URI path at the end. Of course it doesn't make sense to have an `if` there anyway, you could just use `$scheme` directly in the `proxy_pass`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing is that `proxy_pass` when you don't explicitly specify the URI you are proxying to, doesn't touch it too. At all. So you get the exact input URI, e.g. */api2/*.

If you need to tamper with URI while proxying it, you need to use `rewrite` directive. The most simple solution would be doing something like this inside your `location` clause:

```
rewrite ^/api2/(.*) /$1 break;
```

Also not that proxying to the same URL but with two different schemes look redundant. I'd say that you should either terminate TLS on your proxy, or, if the intermediate transport is the subject of compromising, get rid of the plain HTTP.